# Can I get Category with id 1 and all Subcategories of that Category in a single query in Sequelize.js?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have the following database table:

```
Table: Categories
Columns: id, name, parent_id
```

and the following records:

```
1 / Category1 / 0
2 / Category2 / 0
3 / Subcategory1 / 1
4 / Subcategory2 / 1
```

So I have 2 Categories - Category1 and Category2 and 2 Subcategories of Category1 - Subcategory1 and Subcategory2.

If the parent_id field is 0, that means the record is a Category and if it is not 0 and has the id of another category, then it is a subcategory of that category.

Right now I'm getting all Categories like this:

```
Category.findAll({
    where: {
        'parent_id': 0
    }
})
.then(result => {
    console.log(result)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

but now I also want to somehow include the Subcategories of the Categories as an object property. Right now I'm getting this:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Category1",
      "parent_id": 0
    }
]
```

and I want to get something like this:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Category1",
      "parent_id": 0,
      "subcategories": [
          {
              "id": 3,
              "name": "Subcategory1",
              "parent_id": 1,
          },
          {
              "id": 4,
              "name": "Subcategory2",
              "parent_id": 1,
          }
      ]
    }
]
```

It is similar to eager loading but it is like the model eager loading itself. How can I do this in least queries possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `sequelize.define()` to create a `Model` that backs your table, in this case "Category"

```js
// first define your model, you don't have to define the `id` or `parent_id` as they will be created automatically
const Categories = sequelize.define('categories', {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
  },
},
{
  // use underscores in generated column names
  underscored: true,
});
```

Now create the relationships between parent-<children and child--parent for the Model.

```js
// relate a category to its parent=
Categories.belongsTo(Categories, {
  as: 'parent', 
  foreignKey: 'parent_id', 
  targetKey: 'id',
});

// relate parent to child categories
Categories.hasMany(Categories, {
  as: 'subcategories',
  foreignKey: 'parent_id',
});
```

Now you can use the `include` option to pass in the `Model` and specify the `as` parameter to load the correct relationships. Pass in `required: false` to use a left join so that results will come back if there are no subcategories.

```js
// ... your code

// now you can include the subcategories and 
// pass in the parent_id into the where clause
const category = await Categories.findOne({
  include: {
    model: Categories,
    as: 'subcategories',
    required: false,
  },
  where: {
    parent_id: 0,
  },
});

// if you know the ID you want is 1...
const category = await Categories.findByPk(1, {
  include: {
    model: Categories,
    as: 'subcategories',
    required: false,
  },
});
```

In the reverse direction, from the child to the parent, or in this case both...

```js
// To get a category and its parent and children...
const categoryWithParentAndSubcategories = await Categories.findByPk(123, {
  include: [
    {
      model: Categories,
      as: 'parent',
      required: false,
    },
    {
      model: Categories,
      as: 'subcategories',
      required: false,
    },
  ],
});

// you can keep going for multiple levels if you want

// To get a category and its grandparent, parent and children...
const categoryWithParentAndSubcategories = await Categories.findByPk(123, {
  include: [
    {
      model: Categories,
      as: 'parent',
      required: false,
      include: {
        model: Categories,
        as: 'parent',
        required: false,
      },
    },
    {
      model: Categories,
      as: 'subcategories',
      required: false,
    },
  ],
});
```